# Molecular dynamics to reproduce dispersion interactions

Tags: molecular-dynamics, software-recommendations, cp2k, intermolecular-forces, cpmd

I'm trying to simulate the behavior of chromophore molecules incorporated into a polymer under an external electric field.

I've tried to use classical molecular dynamics (GROMACS) but it's unable to reproduce some phenomena such as molecule aggregation due to its dispersion nature.

So I'm looking for a dynamic method/software that is able to reproduce dispersion interactions on the scale of thousands of atoms. I'm personally thinking about CP2K or CPMD but I'm not sure.

Comment: First of all, are you sure the molecules do aggregate in reality? Force fields are coarse methods indeed, but they are not very likely to be qualitatively wrong for dispersion.

Comment: I believe yes, they do aggregate. At least I've seen a couple of papers where some phenomena were attributed to aggregation.

Comment: roma, @wzkchem5: this may be a naive question, but dispersion interactions are typically pairwise (e.g. between 2 atoms), so what is meant by "on the scale of thousands of atoms"?

Comment: @NikeDattani I want to simulate a pretty big system, because I want a meaningful mean values, so I need lots of atoms in total

Comment: Understood, so you're basically looking for a forcefield that has the correct $C_6 / r^6$ dispersion terms in it?

Comment: What forcefields are you using? I would blame the brand of FF, not the use of a FF.

Comment: I believe gromacs has an option to turn on long range dispersion corrections (`DispCorr=EnerPress`). However, according the manual it should only be used for force fields which were parameterized with dispersion corrections (e.g. Amber99). For CHARMM the dispersion should not be used. You can also try the software [xTB](https://github.com/grimme-lab/xtb) which has fast semi-empirical methods and a polarizable force-field.

Comment: @B.Kelly I use OPLS-AA as it the only forcefield I can get parametrization for, using PolyParGen. I think the problem is that in antiparallel aggregate we can't treat two molecules as separate dipoles, instead we have aggregate with almost zero resulting dipole moment.

Comment: Hi romaichenko, was the thinking behind my last comment correct? Also, was the last comment by @SRMaiti helpful at all?

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.